# Unable to access Microsoft Graph API after getting OAuth access_token

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, adal, adal.js

I'm using [adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to generate an access token via Microsoft OAuth, however whenever I try to use the access token to call the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` endpoint (or graph.windows.net), I receive the following error: **Authentication_MissingOrMalformed: Access Token missing or malformed.**

Any ideas on how I can remedy this? Here's my config in JS:

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.12/js/adal.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
      instance: 'https://login.microsoft.com/',     
      tenant: 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx', //COMMON OR YOUR TENANT ID
      clientId: 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx', //REPLACE WITH YOUR CLIENT ID
      redirectUri: '/login.php', //REPLACE WITH YOUR REDIRECT URL
      callback: getUser,
      popUp: true,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
  });

    ...

    authContext.login();
    // SET COOKIE
    var newToken = authContext.getCachedToken('tenantid-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx');
    var now = new Date();
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1 * 3600 * 1000);
    document.cookie = "token="+newToken+"; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
</script>
```

And here's how I'm attempting to pull/use the token in my PHP script:

```
<?php
// Get the token
$token = $_COOKIE['token'];

// Set headers
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Make request to Graph API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.windows.net/mywebsite.org/me?api-version=1.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);
curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($response);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

All it does is return this error: **Authentication_MissingOrMalformed: Access Token missing or malformed.**

How can I fix this?? Is it a problem with not specifying the correct resource?

Comment: Is the issue was fixed? If not please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To call the Azure AD Graph REST successfully, we need to acquire the token for the Azure AD Graph.

To check whether the token is correct for the Azure AD Graph, you can print the token and parse it from [here](https://jwt.io/).

The `aud` claim in the token should be `https://graph.windows.net`. If it does't match, you need to acquire the token using the `acquireToken` instead of getting the token from cache. And the `resource` parameter should be `https://graph.windows.net`.

Comment: Just to add if you want to call the Microsoft Graph the same is true with ```aud``` and ```resource``` param being ```https://graph.microsoft.com```.